# Is there a keyboard shortcut for moving the cursor to the middle of the current line? Can it be created?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I create a custom key binding for moving the cursor to the middle of the current line using Karabiner Elements? Is there is any other way to do this? I can't find anything helpful.

Comment: Can Karabiner elements be used to move the cursor to the middle of the line with respect to the console width, not with respect to the line length?

Comment: I want to achieve this keyboard movement across text editing software such as Google Docs, Word, etc and not on emacs and vim mapping in mac.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Karabiner-Elements manual](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/manual/configuration/configure-complex-modifications/), it doesn't appear that such a keyboard movement is supported. A program that accomplishes this would need to be aware of the full line of text you're typing, like a text editor is.

[This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35599/moving-cursor-to-the-middle-of-the-line-where-it-currently-is) shows how to accomplish this in Emacs with a custom function, and [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2462/how-do-i-move-the-cursor-to-the-center-of-current-line) shows how to accomplish this with a Vim mapping. Out of the box, both have a way to skip to the beginning and ends of lines (`0` and `$` in Vim, `C-a` and `C-e` in Emacs). Both editors also support more advanced cursor movement options that can be used in context to move the cursor to arbitary positions.